# fill numpy array based on distance to nearest values

Tags: python, numpy

So I have a numpy array with a "hole". The hole is always a polygon describing the shape of the missing values, so I always have a continuous border. I want to fill this numpy array not by nearest neighbour but based on the weighted distance (euclidian distance based on indices) to the band of edge values. I am totally lost on how to do this. Since it's image-like data it shouldn't be too inefficient. So imagine I have this array:

```
11111
22022
30003
22022
11111
```

I would first get the border:

```
00100
02020
30003
02020
00100
```

the exact definition of border is not that important...

and then fill the inner missing values for pixel m using: `fill_value = 1/sum_distances*sum_{p in border_pixel} distance_from_to(m,p)*value(p)`

I can't use nearest neighbour solutions since i need to avoid Voronoi-artifacts.

Comment: *... then fill the inner missing values* what missing values? You mean the `0` inside? You should probably update your question with final expected output.

Comment: ah yeah. I'll edit it!